# Break the for loop based on the ajax success variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, for-loop

For the following code, the emailCnt is 50 for first iteration, I need 25 in next iteration. What is the possible way to access the variable value outside the ajax success and break the for loop execution?

```
var limit = 50;
var emailCnt = limit;
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    console.log(emailCnt);///this value is 50 instead I need 25     
    if (emailCnt < limit && i != 0) {
        break;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        submit_post(slNo, limit, function (output) {
            slNo = output;
            emailCnt = 25;
            $('#load_data').html('Hello');
        });
    }, 1000);
}
function submit_post(slNo, limit, handleData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: url,
        data: { slNo: slNo, limit: limit },
        success: function (data) { handleData(data); }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to move your code into the success callback because it is guaranteed to wait until there's a response before proceeding with the rest of the code

Comment: You have an outer loop that has 20 iterations, does that mean normally 50 emails are processed 20 times, so 1000 emals?

Comment: @zer00ne Yes   But the email count in the first iteration should be 50 and 25 in next iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This successfully worked for me

```
var limit           =   50;
var emailCnt        =   limit;
function submit_post(slNo, limit) 
{
    var result="";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: url,
        data: {slNo:slNo, limit:limit},
        success: function(data) { result = data; }
    });
    return result;
}
for(var i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    if(emailCnt     <   limit  &&  i  !=  0)
    {
        break;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
    var output              =   submit_post(slNo, limit); 
    slNo                    =   output;
    emailCnt                =   25;
    $('#load_data').html('Hello');
}, 1000);
}
```